# Microsoft.FluentUI rendering problem on refresh

Tags: blazor, fluent-ui

Have a rendering problem when using FluentUI.
The problem is - when you refresh the page (F5) - it is blinking (looks like initially it's rendered without any styles and only after few milliseconds the styles are applied)

It's easily can be reproduced with using FluentUI template

```
dotnet new install Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Templates
dotnet new fluentblazor --name MyFluentApp
cd MyFluentApp
dotnet run
```

Especially, this is easy to see on `/weather` page

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to eliminate those blinkings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

- for proper styling it needs to load the
   `_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.lib.module.js`
- `blazor.web.js` is the caller for this js library
- `blazor.web.js` is called as last
- content (unstyled) is loaded before the js lib is loaded, thus the blinking.

Solution:

- load the js lib before the content, place this to your `<head>`:

```html
<script src="_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.lib.module.js"></script>
```

- note that instead of blinking it will show nothing, thus might look "slow".
- also note that when you disable cache (in browser dev tools) this workaround wont work - because it loads the js lib and `blazor.web.js` will load it again.

Comment: Possibly it was workaround for some previous versions. Not working for the latest. Found other additions: `<script src="_content/Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components/js/loading-theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <loading-theme storage-name="theme"></loading-theme>`, but these don't help much. Button on `/counter` page is jumping when page is refreshed.